# Error when installing Spinnaker on Kubernetes on prem cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I'm trying to install Spinnaker on a Kubernetes setup onprem.

Following instructions from https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/

- Install and run Halyard as Docker on the Kubernetes master.
- Run everything as root
- mkdir ~/.hal  on Kubemaster. Created the service account as instrcuted in the site.
- Copied the kubeconfig file from ./kube/config into ~/.hal/kubeconfig as it didnt work with docker -v option, there was some permission issue, so made it work this way
- docker run halyard command -- all up and running fine.
- Ran Bash and Inside halyard.

Now when I do these two things inside halyard

- Point kubectl to the kubeconfig by export KUBECONFIG command
- Enable kubernetes provider "hal config provider kubernetes enable"

The command gets executed sometimes successfully or it fails with this warning after timeout error

- Getting object contents of versions.yml

Unexpected error comparing versions: com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.core.error.v1.HalException: Could not load "versions.yml" from config bucket: www.googleapis.com.*

Even if it somehow manages to run successfully. When I run these,

```
CONTEXT=$(kubectl config current-context)

hal config provider kubernetes account add my-k8s-account --context $CONTEXT
```

It fails with the same error as above.

Total weird stuff. Its intermittent. Does it have something to do with the kubeconfig file? Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what platform/infrastructure are you using? Which k8s version?

Comment: I installed a standalone K8s cluster on Azure to simulate on prem. Kubernetes was installed thro Kubespray, version is 1.17. Firewalls are disabled on the Kubemaster and Azure firewalls allow all outbound and accepts 22, 6443 and 443  inbound

Comment: Also checked that from inside the VM, I'm able to  telnet googleapis.com 443
Trying 172.253.122.105...
Connected to googleapis.com.
Escape character is '^]'. But from inside the halyard container, I'm getting below issue when trying to wget. bash-5.0$ wget www.googleapis.com:443
Connecting to www.googleapis.com:443 (172.217.13.74:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.217.13.74): Operation timed out

Comment: Do You have any network connectivity from inside the halyard container?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Azure support recommended installing a CNI plugin and it resolved the issue. So, it seems like inside of Azure VM without a Public IP, the CNI plugin is needed for a VM To connect to internet.

Comment: I have combined our findings into community wiki answer for better visibility in our community.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments these kind of errors could result when there lack of network connectivity from inside the container.

As Vikram mentioned in his comment:

> Yes, that was the problem. Azure support recommended installing a CNI plugin and it resolved the issue. So, it seems like inside of Azure VM without a Public IP, the CNI plugin is needed for a VM To connect to internet.

To configure CNI plugin on Azure platform use this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni).

Hope it helps.